# my dropdownlist isnt showing in my webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, webforms

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="Charting.aspx.cs" Inherits="Charting" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" tagprefix="asp" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <table style="border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial">
<tr>
        <td>
        <b>Select Chart Type:</b>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="350px">
            <Titles>
                <asp:Title Text="Total marks of students">
                </asp:Title>
            </Titles>
           <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Bar">
                    <Points>
                        <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Tommy" YValues="88,0,0,0,0,0" />
                                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Jane" YValues="55,0,0,0,0,0" />
                                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Julia" YValues="66,0,0,0,0,0" />
                                <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Jack" YValues="80,0,0,0,0,0" />
                               <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Zachary" YValues="78,0,0,0,0,0" />
                    </Points>
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisX Title="Student Name">
                </AxisX>
                <AxisY Title="Total Marks">
                </AxisY>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>
</td>
</tr>
</table>


</asp:Content>
```

I have the same code implemented without the masterpage but the dropdownlist is showing, however when when i try to implement the dropout list in a webform with masterpage, it doesnt show! anyone knows what happened?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GetChartTypes();
    }
}

private void GetChartTypes()
{
    foreach (int chartType in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SeriesChartType)))
    {
        ListItem li = new ListItem(Enum.GetName(typeof(SeriesChartType),
            chartType), chartType.ToString());
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

The above codes are from my aspx.cs file to get the chart types and creating and filling up the options for the dropdownlist

Comment: We’ll likely need to see your code behind. What does the code that populates your dropdown list look like?

Comment: Put `DropDownList1.DataBind()` under the foreach loop.